# How to indicate "exactly equals" occurrence constraint in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I found out that it is possible to restrict the minimum and the maximum number of elements in a XML Schema.

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string"
      maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I want  to restrinct the number of elements to an exact number. 
Is there a `numberOfOccurs`, or something like that?
I could make it by setting the minOccurs to a value that is equal to maxOccurs... for example..

```
<xs:element name="person">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="full_name" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="child_name" type="xs:string"
      maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="10"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there a specific way for doing it?

Answer (score 2):

There is no separate cardinality constraint such as `exactlyOccurs` -- just use `minOccurs` and `maxOccurs` set to the same value as you've anticipated.

Comment: But be careful about what you are asking for: every constraint like this comes back to bite you eventually. Yes, of course there are exactly four quarters in every year. But what about the current year, or the year you started, or the year you were acquired by another company? Remember that integrity constraints are rules that prevent users doing what they want, including things that they want for a good reason.